# dojoconfig.map while running against a CDN (built source)

Tags: dojo

I am running into a dojo library bug that I am trying to resolve before our upcoming release.  The issue is localized to a single file (`dojo/on`) and I am able to fix the bug by making changes to `dojo/on`.

The way that I have attempted to fix this is to use the `map` property in `dojoConfig`.

Dojo config:

```
dojoConfig = {
    ... other stuff ...
    map: {
        "*": {
            "dojo/on": "myPackage/patches/on"
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to fixing the issue in `dojo/on`, I also replaced the relative paths in require with absolute paths.  The new `on` looks like this:

```
define(["dojo/has!dom-addeventlistener?:dojo/aspect", "dojo/_base/kernel", "dojo/sniff"], function(aspect, dojo, has){

    "use strict";

    alert("HI From new on - I only work with unbuilt dojo");    // Rest of on is the same.
```

This works great when I am running against dojo source.

When I run against a CDN this stops working.  As far as I can see `myPackage/patches/on` is never loaded (firebug net panel & fiddler).  The other odd thing that happens is these requests are made to my server:

```
http://.../patches/dojo-1.9.4/has.js
http://.../patches/dojo-1.9.4/sniff.js
http://.../patches/dojo-1.9.4/_base/kernel.js
```

The result is that the page doesn't load and the console shows no other errors.

---

**Edit** - Full sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <script>
    dojoConfig = {
        parseOnLoad: true,
        packages: [
            {name: "my", location: "//localhost/dojoSandbox" }
        ],
        map: {
            "*": {
                "dojo/on" : "my/patches/on-dojo-1.9.4"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Using a CDN doesn't work.  Crap -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Using dojo source works great!
    <script src="//localhost/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <link href="//localhost/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    -->

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="hSliderDiv"></div>
    <script>
        require(["dijit/form/HorizontalSlider", "dojo/domReady!"], function(HorizontalSlider){
                new HorizontalSlider({
                    onChange: function(value){
                        console.log(value);
                    }
                }, "hSliderDiv").startup();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Console:

[image]